# Regular expression help needed in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

Can anyone help me form a regex to identify the pattern `dd-ddd` as a whole word in a sentence e.g. in a sentence like this -

`11-222` should be matched at the beginning of the sentence, as well as `33-444` in the middle but not `55-66-777` since the whole word does not match the pattern. If the pattern is present at the end, that should also be matched like `88-999`

If I use a regex expression like `'\b\d{2}-\d{3}\b'` it even matches `66-777` which is within `55-66-777`. I need to exclude that. Somehow, - (hyphen) is treated as a boundary for a word.

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Added sample code and output

```
import re
regex_str = r'\b\d{2}-\d{3}\b'
msg_message = '11-222 should be matched, as well as 33-444 but not 55-66-777. If it is present at the end, that should also be matched like 88-999'
for match in re.finditer(regex_str, msg_message):
    print('*'*15)
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.span())
```

O/p

```
***************
11-222
(0, 6)
***************
33-444
(37, 43)
***************
66-777
(55, 61)
***************
88-999
(125, 131)
```

Comment: Use space instead? `(^|\s)\d{2}-\d{3}(\s|$)`

Comment: Use `(?<!\S)\d{2}-\d{3}(?!\S)`

Comment: actually it can come at the beginning of the sentence too, so space at the front will not work. Same for end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `(?<!\S)\d{2}-\d{3}(?!\S)`. This pattern ensures a whitespace character (or no character - i.e. start/end of string) before and after.

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/ueeKAO/1)

How it works:

- `(?<!\S)` ensure what precedes doesn't match a non-whitespace character
- `\d{2}` match two digits
- `-` match this character literally
- `\d{3}` match three digits
- `(?!\S)` ensure what follows doesn't match a non-whitespace character

The double negatives are used purposely. The alternative is to use `(?<=\s|^)` and `(?=\s|$)` respectively (but it's longer and less sexy).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match your pattern but *not preceded by a hyphen*

`(?<!\-)\d{2}\-\d{3}`

```
import re
regex_str = r'\b(?<!\-)\d{2}\-\d{3}\b'
msg_message = '11-222 should be matched, as well as 33-444 but not 55-66-777. If it is present at the end, that should also be matched like 88-999'
for match in re.finditer(regex_str, msg_message):
    print('*'*15)
    print(match.group(0))
    print(match.span())

***************
11-222
(0, 6)
***************
33-444
(37, 43)
***************
88-999
(125, 131)
```

You could do the same with a negative lookahead `(?!\-)` if you want to apply the  same treatment to the right side of your expression.

Comment: This seems to be working. Many thanks! I will try to validate this some other examples. Thanks again!

Comment: This incorrectly matches the first part of digits in the format `11-111-1...`

Comment: @Digi The same linked page tells you how to do negative lookaheads. If you also want to enforce the same condition on the right side of your string, use a negative lookahead too.

Comment: @ctwheels, that was not part of the question. Regardless, if OP runs into that problem, the answer is in the page I linked.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it might not be explicitly written in the question, but the OP did specifically state *pattern `dd-ddd` as a **whole word***

Comment: @ctwheels, _ugh, alright!_ I'll add it to my answer. I don't think it's StackOverflow's job to preemptively feed OP the answer to questions they might have, especially when this seems more a case of not knowing what to google rather than a question with their algorithm. Giving people the answer without encouraging them to look for themselves tells them that it's okay to not do their own research first and is one of the reason we see so many no-research questions on SO.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi agreed. We see this a lot with regex. Unfortunately, regex is a lesser known utility of most languages and causes quite a bit of confusion. If we don't give them a full answer, they often come back and ask a second question as a follow up of the first one. Then you end up with double the questions :/ lose-lose situation either way haha.

Comment: @ctwheels, Pranav - thanks for your inputs. I did mention about 'whole word' but possibly did not illustrate this enough in the example string. However, based on Pranav's initial suggestion I was able to look up and figure out the negative lookahead needed for the right hand as well. And yes, the double negation with S is what I need in my case, because it could be characters other than hypen that I need to handle. Thanks again, not only your answers but the details were the most helpful.